# ag-grid enterprise Set Filter "(blanks)"-binding not working

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In order to save the user work, I save several column filters in the sessionstorage. Recently the Enterprise Set Filter has been added and it works almost fine.
The only problem is that the empty columns are not taken when I add them back to the filter with the setFilterModel() from the api.

I did following:

The user adds a new Set Filter and selects (blanks) as value. The filter was changed and the (filterChanged) event was fired. I get the current filter from the api with api.getFilterModel() and saved the result as JSON string with JSON.stringify(currentFilter) in the sessionstorage.

```
getFilter() {
const currentFilter = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();
if (Object.keys(currentFilter).length !== 0) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('filterKey', JSON.stringify(currentFilter));
 }
}
```

If the user opens the page again, the filter should be taken over again.

```
setFilter() {
const currentFilter = sessionStorage.getItem('filterKey');
if (currentFilter) {
  const filter = JSON.parse(currentFilter);
  this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(filter);
  this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
 } 
}
```

This method was called by the (rowDataChanged) event.

This is working with the text, date, number and set filter except blank values.
If blank values are selected, i get the following model:

```
{
"column" : "nameOfColumn": {
    "filterType": "set",
    "values": [null]
  }
}
```

But the binding to null is not working if I apply the filter. I know, that the JSON.parse do not add null into array's, so I've tried to add null manually to get the same result.

How can I save and apply null values in the set filter?

Thanks!

Comment: Discovered this is finally fixed in the latest AG Grid Enterprise 27.0.1

Comment: In case someone still looking at this, it's the same issue mentioned in this github link: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4914